# New MBP 13 retina late 2013 battery problem

Tags: battery, macbook-pro

I just have bought new MBP 13 retina late 2013 and after installing: adobe photoshop, office for mac 2011, xcode, eclipse, java, and MAMP is battery life too short. 100% charched battery is remaining only 4 hours. If I use guest account it is normal about 8 - 9 hours... After shut down, when I first log in to guest acc (not to my acc) it is really great (8 hours). But if I first log in to my acc and after i logout and log in to guest it is still only 4 hours. It is like some of these programs eat my battery. But in activity monitor is all right... What do you think? Where can be problem?

Thanks for replies
I have OS X Mavericks (10.9.1)

Comment: Maybe MAMP is running in background.

Comment: Only Mamp is eating the battery i tested if mamp is running its like half the battery life idk why maybe its a app bug.

Answer (score 1):

MAMP. quit out of MAMP and you will see vast improvement.